# Get the wrong answer——about uncertain number of variables

Tags: c, variadic-functions, function-definition

When I ran the program below in the Linux system, I can't get the expected answer "9". But I can get it in the windows system.

Why does this happen?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int num, ...){
    int* p = &num + 1;
    int res = 0;
    while(num--){
        res += *p++;
    }
    return res;
}


int main(){
    printf("%d\n", sum(3,2,3,4));
    return 0;

}
```

I debug it in GDB, shown as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knk8e.png)

My System configuration is below.

> Linux version 5.11.0-41-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-005) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34)

Comment: regarding: `res += *p++;`   this will have a precedence problem.  Suggest: `res += (*p)++;`

Comment: regarding: `int* p = &num + 1;`  depending on if the stack us built upward or downward, This will not access any of the parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use macros defined in the header `<stdarg.h>`.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

long long int sum( size_t n, ... ) 
{
    long long int result = 0;

    va_list ap;

    va_start( ap, n );

    while (n--)
    {
        result += va_arg( ap, int );
    }

    va_end( ap );

    return result;
}

int main( void )
{
    printf( "%lld\n", sum( 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
45
```

Comment: I got it! Thanks for your help.

Comment: I still wonder why I can get the expected result by running my program in the CLion of Windows system, but didn't in the GCC of Linux.

Comment: @Breeze It seems to your different alignment.